# How many ways are there so that there 4 runs of A and B?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a sequence of 10 A's and 8 B's.By a run we mean one or more consecutive A's and B's.Here AAABBAABAABBBAAABB is sequence of 4 runs of A and 4 runs of B.How many ways of arrangements are there having four runs of A and 4 runs of B?

Answer (score 1):

Start with $ABABABAB$ or $BABABABA$, two possibilities.

With stars and bars we find that there are $\binom{9}{3}$ ways to
divide the $6$ letters $A$ that are left in $4$ parts. E.g. $AA,A,,AAA$.

Here $AA$ joins the first $A$ in $ABABABAB$ (and $BABABABA$), 
$A$ joins the second $A$ in $ABABABAB$ and $BABABABA$, no $A$ will join the third and $AAA$ will join the fourth.

Likewise there are $\binom{7}{3}$ ways to
divide the $4$ letters $B$ that are left in $4$ parts. E.g. $B,,B,BBB$.

This gives $$2\times\binom{9}{3}\times\binom{7}{3}$$ arrangements with
$4$ runs of $A$ and $4$ runs of $B$.

The example mentioned results in $AAABBAABABBAAAABBBB$ and $BBAAABAABBABBBBAAAA$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: This is equivalent to asking for the number of ways to:

- break sequence of 10 A's into 4 segments
- break sequence of 8 B's into 4 segments
- Alternate these segments (beware of double counting!)